# Linq Expression Trees and Filtering Logic

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I am new to Linq Expressions.

I am calling an API, that exposes the following overloaded methods:

```
CustomPaging<TEntity> GetAll(int index, int maxPage, Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> keySelector, OrderBy orderBy = OrderBy.Ascending);

CustomPaging<TEntity> GetAll(int index, int maxPage, Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> keySelector, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, OrderBy orderBy, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] useProperties)
```

My intent is to pass an "id" parameter as part of a predicate in order to filter by the passed value.

Something along the lines of:

```
x => x.UserId.Equals(id)
```

My question - is it possible to determine, from the API's method signature, how to achieve this filtering?

I have played around with passing in variations on the following to no avail:

```
 Expression<Func<Group, int>> myFunc = u => u.UserId == id
```

> Error: Cannot convert bool to int.

```
Func<Group, int> myFunc = g => g.UserId == id;
```

> Error: Cannot convert from System.Func to
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

I obviously don't understand Expression Trees very well and could use some friendly guidance. Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: You should have a look at Joseph Albahari's Predicate Builder.  http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: `u.UserId == id` returns a boolean value and `Expression<Func<Group, int>>` expects an `int` return type. You're just confused with the parameters, `keySelector` is not the parameter responsible for filtering, it is the next parameter named `predicate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `perdicate` of type `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` is the parameter responsible for filtering:

```
Expression<Func<Group, bool>> myFunc = u => u.UserId == id;
```

You need to match the signature of `<Group, bool>` and not `<Group, int>`

The final call can be:

```
var results = GetAll(someIndex, someMaxPage, x=> x.UserId, u => u.UserId == id);
```

or:

```
Expression<Func<Group, int>> myKeySelector = u => u.UserId;
Expression<Func<Group, bool>> myFilter = u => u.UserId == id;
var results = GetAll(someIndex, someMaxPage, myKeySelector, myFunc );
```

Comment: That's an `Expression<Func<Group, bool>>` not `Expression<Func<Group, int>>`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Correct. Updated.

Comment: It doesn't look like an assignment operator is being used in the OP.  Ninja edit, maybe?

Comment: I mean, this question is *still*, unanswerable - the error message doesn't match the code, and OP doesn't seem to know what he's doing. He most probably just needs `u => u.UserId` given the `keySelector` variable name.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski He's just confused with which parameter is responsible for filtering. That's it I think. Answer updated !

Comment: Thanks for that, Lucas. I think it is obvious that I am new to Expressions from the post. So, can somebody explain how the variable gets passed.

Comment: OK, thanks user3185569. That seems to work. It seems I was treating the keySelector as the filter, which was getting me turned around. Sorted now. Thanks.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I think the updated answer perfectly answers this question.

Comment: @user3185569 You seem to think that downvote is mine... it's not. But yeah, looks like you guessed right.